# Excel crashes when copying worksheet to new workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

Select option to move or copy workbook to new workbook. Fatal error.

Select option to move or copy workbook within same workbook, OK.

Only crashes when copy to new. No specific error message, says "Microsoft Excel has stopped working".

Tried clearing conditional formats, cleared a bunch of calculations errors, checked directory permissions - no change. No VBA in file, xlsx format.

Excel 2013, 32bit.

Has anyone else encountered this?

EDIT:

Recovered an error message code:

Additional information about the problem:
   LCID: 1033
   skulcid: 1033

Comment: 32-bit hints at potential memory issues - how big is the document & what else do you have using RAM at the same time?

Comment: I am doubtful but any clues in Event Log?

Comment: 32bit was my thought - I've experienced that before with lots of conditional formatting but last time that gave a specific "out of resources" error - plus why is it working in the same workbook?! Strange.

Comment: Sadly, can't open event log as on a restricted machine with no admin functions available.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to rework the problem at hand.

Write code to copy the existing file.
Then open it, make the changes/edits need.
Then save and close.
Done

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1137593)